# Numeric Overflow com Numeric(18,7) no Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Preciso de uma precisão de 7 casas em um determinado cálculo com divisão, porém quando o divisor é muito pequeno, gera um número extenso. Quando tento dar o cast, dá numeric overflow, mesmo o número "cabendo" no cast. O sql é o seguinte:

```
select
   cast(2012 as numeric(18,7))
  ,cast(0.01 as numeric(18,7))
  ,cast(2012 as numeric(18,7)) / cast(0.01 as numeric(18,7)) VALOR
from ...
```

Os dois primeiros campos geram corretamente, mas se fizer a divisão retorna o erro. O resultado da divisão seria 201.200.00, que cabe no numeric(18,7).

Testei dessa forma:

```
select
   cast(2012 as numeric(18,7))
  ,cast(0.01 as numeric(18,7))
  ,cast(2012 as numeric(18,7)) / cast(0.01 as numeric(18,6)) VALOR
from ...
```

Se der o segundo cast com 18,6, funciona, mas em outros cálculos da mesma tabela vou perder 1 dígito de precisão.

Estou utilizando Firebird 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é comum ao lidar com esse tipo de dado. Acontece que o resultado de uma multiplicação `Numeric(18,7) * Numeric(18,7)` é maior que o tipo Numeric pode aceitar.
Numa multiplicação `Numeric(a,b) * Numeric(a,b)` o resultado é um tipo `Numeric(a,b+b)`.
No seu caso isso quer dizer que o resultado é o abaixo que você pode ver que é impossível ser executado:

```
SELECT
  cast( 2012/0.01 as numeric(18,14)) 
FROM rdb$database
```

Nestes casos, muitas vezes o melhor é trocar a ordem das operações ou converter para `DOUBLE PRECISION` antes de fazer a operação e converter novamente para o tipo desejado no final. Exemplo:

```
SELECT
  CAST(CAST(CAST(2012 AS NUMERIC(18,7)) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) / CAST(CAST(0.01 AS NUMERIC(18,6)) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) AS NUMERIC(18,6)) AS valor
FROM rdb$database
```

Isso não causaria maiores problemas para perder precisão:

```
SELECT
   CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(18,6)) / CAST(3 AS NUMERIC(18,6))
   ,CAST(CAST(CAST(1 AS NUMERIC(18,7)) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) / CAST(CAST(3 AS NUMERIC(18,6)) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) AS NUMERIC(18,6))
FROM rdb$database
```

**Atualização:**
Os seguintes links podem ajudar a entender mais sobre esse problema:

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq79/

http://www.firebase.com.br/artigo.php?id=104

Comment: Pefeito, dei o cast para double precision na execução do cálculo e de volta parar Numeric(18,7) depois, ficou certinho. Obrigado!

Comment: @Vinicius que bom que ajudou. Apenas garanta fazer os testes necessários. Essa parte de precisão é sempre complicada.

Answer (score 1):

Em literais Firebird com um ponto `decimal` são do tipo `NUMERIC` , não `DOUBLE` `PRECISION` (ou outro tipo de ponto flutuante). Isso significa que ele irá aplicar as suas regras de cálculo numéricos exatos.

Assim, com `select 187/60.00 from rdb$database` isso significa que 187 é um `INTEGER` e 60,00 é um `NUMERIC(18,2)`

> Se dois operandos OP1 e OP2 são numérico exato com escala S1 e S2,
>   respectivamente, em seguida, OP1 + OP2 e OP1-OP2 são numérico exato
>   com precisão de 18 e dimensionar o maior de S1 e S2, enquanto OP1 *
>   OP2 e OP1 / OP2 são numérico exato com precisão 18 e S1 escala + S2.
>   (As escalas destes operação, exceto divisão são especificados pelo
>   padrão SQL A norma faz a precisão de todas estas operações, ea escala
>   de Divison, definida implementação em:. Definimos a precisão de 18
>   anos, e a escala de divisão como S1 + S2, o mesmo que é exigido pela
>   norma, no caso da multiplicação.)

Quando um dos operandos é um tipo integral, ele é considerado como um numérico com escala 0. Portanto, neste caso você tem `NUMERIC(18,0)/NUMERIC(18,2)` e com base nas regras acima, o resultado é `NUMERIC(18, 0+2) = NUMERIC(18,2) .`

O facto de o número parece estar truncada é um resultado da aplicação de cálculo numérico exacta: o cálculo pára quando o último digito foi calculada. O fato de que há um resto não tem qualquer influência sobre o resultado do cálculo:

```
60.00 / 187 \ 3.11 180 --- 70 60 -- 100 60 -- (stop) 40
```

Olhando para o SQL: 2011 especificação Fundação o fato de Firebird considera 60.00 para ser um numérico exato é correta, já que tem as seguintes regras de produção para literais na secção 5.3 :

```
<literal> ::=
    <signed numeric literal>
  | <general literal>

<unsigned literal> ::=
    <unsigned numeric literal>
  | <general literal>

<signed numeric literal> ::=
    [ <sign> ] <unsigned numeric literal>

<unsigned numeric literal> ::=
    <exact numeric literal>
  | <approximate numeric literal>

<exact numeric literal> ::=
    <unsigned integer> [ <period> [ <unsigned integer> ] ]
  | <period> <unsigned integer>

<sign> ::=
    <plus sign>
  | <minus sign>

<approximate numeric literal> ::=
    <mantissa> E <exponent>

<mantissa> ::=
    <exact numeric literal>

<exponent> ::=
    <signed integer>

<signed integer> ::=
    [ <sign> ] <unsigned integer>

<unsigned integer> ::=
    <digit>...
```

E regras de sintaxe:

> 21) Um  sem  tem um implícita 
>   após a última  .  22) O tipo declarado de uma  ENL é um tipo numérico exato definido pela implementação cuja
>   escala é o número de  s à direita do  . Haverá um tipo
>   numérico exato capaz de representar o valor de ENL exatamente.

Seção 6.27  especifica as seguintes regras de sintaxe:

> 1) Se o tipo declarado de ambos os operandos de um operador aritmético
>   dyadic é numérico exato, em seguida, o tipo declarado do resultado é
>   um tipo numérico exato definido pela implementação, com precisão e
>   escala determinada da seguinte forma:  a) Seja S1 e S2 ser a escala do
>   primeiro e segundo operandos respectivamente.  b) A precisão do
>   resultado da adição e subtração é definido pela implementação, ea
>   escala é o máximo de S1 e S2.  c) A precisão do resultado da
>   multiplicação é definido pela implementação, ea escala é S1 + S2.  d)
>   A precisão ea escala do resultado da divisão é definido pela
>   implementação.  Em outras palavras, o comportamento do Firebird está
>   em conformidade com o padrão SQL. Ao que parece a maioria do outro
>   banco de dados que você tentou (com a possível exceção do SQL Server),
>   use um valor relativamente grande para a escala quando se realiza
>   divisão, ou parecem usar o comportamento aproximado numérico (aka
>   precisão dupla).

Uma solução alternativa seria usar um literal numérico aproximado. Uso de expoente zero ou E0 fará com que o número de precisão dupla, sem poderes de dez. Por exemplo:

```
select 187E0/60.00 from rdb$database; -- result: 3.116666666666667
    -- or 
select 187/60.00E0 from rdb$database; -- result: 3.116666666666667
```

[stackoverflow Gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128353/why-does-firebird-truncate-decimal-places-when-dividing)

Comment: boa ideia, mas o problema continua...

Comment: Já tentou dividir sem o cast?

Comment: Sim, perde a precisão. Se implementar por exemplo cast(1.00 / 3.00 as numeric(18,7)) vai resultar em 0.3333000.